I am getting Error in GooglePay pop ( USE OTHER METHOD OR_CCREU_06 )
I have web application in c# and angular Views. the application about reservation of Hotels. My Manager assign me a Task to integrate google pay in This application But after hitting googlepay button popup appaers but after filling the information i a getting error Chose Other payment Metod.
Please help me in this how i can process
Thanks
I am using this scripts to show button in my web controller page
<% if (IsSeamless == 1) { %>
 <script  async

src="https://pay.google.com/gp/p/js/pay.js"
onload="onGooglePayLoaded()">
        <script>
            /**
     * Define the version of the Google Pay API referenced when creating your
     * configuration
     *
     * @see {@link https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentDataRequest|apiVersion in PaymentDataRequest}
     */
            const baseRequest = {
                apiVersion: 2,
                apiVersionMinor: 0
            };


            const allowedCardNetworks = ["AMEX", "DISCOVER", "INTERAC", "JCB", "MASTERCARD", "VISA"];


            const allowedCardAuthMethods = ["PAN_ONLY", "CRYPTOGRAM_3DS"];


            const tokenizationSpecification = {
                //type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                //parameters: {
                //    "gateway": "payu",
                //    "gatewayMerchantId": "134806"
                //}

                type: 'PAYMENT_GATEWAY',
                parameters: {
                    'gateway': 'example',
                    'gatewayMerchantId': 'exampleGatewayMerchantId'
                }
            };


            const baseCardPaymentMethod = {
                type: 'CARD',
                parameters: {
                    allowedAuthMethods: allowedCardAuthMethods,
                    allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
                }
            };


            const cardPaymentMethod = Object.assign(
                {},
                baseCardPaymentMethod,
                {
                    tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
                }
            );


            let paymentsClient = null;


            function getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest() {
                return Object.assign(
                    {},
                    baseRequest,
                    {
                        allowedPaymentMethods: [baseCardPaymentMethod]
                    }
                );
            }


            function getGooglePaymentDataRequest() {
                const paymentDataRequest = Object.assign({}, baseRequest);
                paymentDataRequest.allowedPaymentMethods = [cardPaymentMethod];
                paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();
                paymentDataRequest.merchantInfo = {

                    merchantId: 'BCR2DN4T7WMLX7YI',
                    merchantName: 'ZainKhan.co'
                };
                return paymentDataRequest;
            }

            function getGooglePaymentsClient() {

                if (paymentsClient === null) {
                    paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({ environment: 'TEST' });
                }
                console.log(paymentsClient);
                return paymentsClient;

            }


            function onGooglePayLoaded() {
                const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
                paymentsClient.isReadyToPay(getGoogleIsReadyToPayRequest())
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.result) {
                            addGooglePayButton();

                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {

                        console.error(err);
                    });
            }


            function addGooglePayButton() {
                const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
                const button =
                    paymentsClient.createButton({ onClick: onGooglePaymentButtonClicked });
                document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
            }


            function getGoogleTransactionInfo() {
                return {
                    countryCode: 'AE',
                    currencyCode: 'AED',
                    totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
                    // set to cart total
                    totalPrice: '10.00'
                };
            }


            function prefetchGooglePaymentData() {
                const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();

                paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = {
                    totalPriceStatus: 'NOT_CURRENTLY_KNOWN',
                    currencyCode: 'AED'
                };
                const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
                paymentsClient.prefetchPaymentData(paymentDataRequest);
            }


            function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
                const paymentDataRequest = getGooglePaymentDataRequest();
                paymentDataRequest.transactionInfo = getGoogleTransactionInfo();

                const paymentsClient = getGooglePaymentsClient();
                paymentsClient.loadPaymentData(paymentDataRequest)
                    .then(function (paymentData) {
                        // handle the response
                        processPayment(paymentData);

                    })
                    .catch(function (err) {
                        // show error in developer console for debugging
                        console.error(err);
                    });
            }


            function processPayment(paymentData) {
                debugger

                console.log(paymentData);
                // @todo pass payment token to your gateway to process payment
                paymentToken = paymentData.paymentMethodData.tokenizationData.token;
            }

        </script>


<% } %>


We couldn’t complete this action. Try a different payment method or contact us. Learn more [OR_CCREU_02]
Now i am getting this while saving the address
